# Change context path of war and uable to add JSP folder using ant

Tags: tomcat, ant

I am trying to deploy a war file in tomcat.The name of project is ANTWarDemo

**build.xml**

```
    <target name="war">
         <war warfile="ANTWarDemo.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
           <fileset dir="${src.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="WebContent/JSP">
                <include name="*.jsp"/>
            </fileset>
           <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
           <classes dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" />
        </war>
<antcall target="deploy"/>
</target>

<target name="deploy">
    <copy file="${base}/ANTWarDemo.war" todir="${tomcat.deploy}"/>
</target>
```

**Question1**

I want to change the context path of my application from ANTWarDemo to myservlet.

**Question2**

I am unable to create a JSP folder in war file using fileset.

Can anyone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: Generate a war file named myservlet.war instead of generating a file named ANTWarDemo.war.

Question 2: You're currently adding, directly into the war, all the .jsp files found under WebContent/JSP. What you want is

```
<fileset dir="WebContent">
    <include name="JSP/*.jsp"/>
</fileset>
```

or

```
<fileset dir="WebContent">
    <include name="JSP/**/*.jsp"/>
</fileset>
```

if you also want to include .jsp files that are in subdirectories.